# What causes "illegal invocation error" in this f.apply

Tags: javascript

```
'use strict';

function delay(f, ms) {

  return function() {
    setTimeout(() => f.apply(this, arguments), ms); //Illegal invocation
  };

}

let obj = {length: 20};
obj.f1000 = delay(alert, 1000);

obj.f1000(this.length);
```

Why do I get illegal invocation error? If the value of this is obj, then the function should just alert "20" without any problems?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Because you're calling `alert` with a `this` value it doesn't expect: your object. The reason that's happening is that you're calling the traditional function that `delay` returns as a method (`obj.f1000`), which means during the call to the function `this` refers to the object, and you're passing `this` as the first argument to `apply` in `f.apply(this, arguments)`. So `alert` sees your object as `this`.

To fix it, use `null` or `undefined` instead of `this` with `apply`:

```js
'use strict';

function delay(f, ms) {

  return function() {
    setTimeout(() => f.apply(null, arguments), ms); //Illegal invocation
// −−−−−−−−−−−−−−−−−−−−−−−−−−^^^^
  };

}

let obj = {length: 20};
obj.f1000 = delay(alert, 1000);

obj.f1000(this.length);
```

*(You could also use `window` if you wanted.)*

Comment: Now I am getting an alert with "0".

Comment: @DaddyMike - `this` in `obj.f1000(this.length)` doesn't have anything to do with `obj`. `this.length` at global scope refers to the [`length` property of the window object](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/API/Window/length), which is the number of frames it contains. In the above, it doesn't contain any frames.

Comment: So how can I get it to refer to obj?

Comment: @DaddyMike - You can't change the value of `this` at global scope. If you want to pass `obj.length` in, do that explicitly: `obj.f1000(obj.length)`. (But this doesn't have anything to do with the question that was asked, which was about the invalid invocation error.)